# Number of elementary binary operations (EBO's) required for Long multiplication in binary

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, binary, analysis-of-algorithms

[image]

How do they get the total of $≤2kl$ EBOs? Shouldn't it require $kl+k(l-1)=2kl-k$ EBOs? And where does the upper bounding "$≤$" come from?